# Apache see index as index.php

Tags: macos, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a small problem: Apche on my Mac OS X 10.8.1 sees `/index` and `/index.php` as same file. That is when referring to the `/index` it load `index.php` like some `RewriteRule`. `DirectoryIndex index.html` as default.

P.S.

Also is other [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216563/apache-2-treating-index-and-index-php-as-the-same-file), but with no working solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function of [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews).  You can disable it in your `.htaccess` like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
```